# How to insert N rows of default values into a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, insert

I have a table containing an identity column as well as a column representing the creation date:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.OrderStatus
(
    OrderStatusId int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    CreationDate datetime NOT NULL default GETDATE(),
    CONSTRAINT PK_OrderStatus PRIMARY KEY(OrderStatusId)
)
```

Since the identity column generates a value by itself and the CreationDate is always going to be the current date (`GETDATE()`), I can add a row thanks to `DEFAULT VALUES`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.OrderStatus DEFAULT VALUES;
```

But what can I do if I want to add, let's say, three records?

**Current solution (edited some input since it didn't make any sense)**

For now, in order to do what I want, I add several rows with `VALUES`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.OrderStatus (CreationDate)
VALUES  (GETDATE()), 
        (GETDATE()), 
        (GETDATE())
```

Although, I'd prefer to know the equivalent of `INSERT INTO .. DEFAULT VALUES` for multiple rows, in case that I add another column with a default value later on.

Is there a way to insert N rows into a table with `DEFAULT VALUES` or in a similar way?

Comment: what are you achieving by removing default GETDATE()

Comment: What's the purpose here - why do you need 3 "default" records?

Comment: @Sagar Actually, my mind bugged on that one. I'm not achieving anything. Although, I'm still interested in the `INSERT INTO DEFAULT VALUES` equivalent for multiple rows.

Comment: @DStanley I know that seems strange, but I want to create a table for the order statuses and then create a junction table between the orderStatus and language tables, which will contain the translations for each status. So, I already know that I need 5 status records for now and then the admins will be able to add additional ones from the app.

Comment: @BishopBarber Yes that does seem a bit strange, but it may make your job easier - could you not just add a record relating to each language rather than "default" records?

Comment: @DStanley A record relating to each language will be added in the table OrderStatusLang (junction table). The OrderStatus table only contains the very basic information of a status. The reason I didn't put it all in one single table is that it makes it easier to create a procedure which will return the statuses depending on the selected language in the application.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use your original definition and just use a while loop, for example

```
DECLARE  @OrderStatus TABLE
(
    OrderStatusId int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
    CreationDate datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()
    --CONSTRAINT PK_OrderStatus PRIMARY KEY(OrderStatusId) -- this can be uncommented if creating a real table.
)


DECLARE @i int = 0;

WHILE @i < 100 -- insert 100 rows.  change this value to whatever you want.
BEGIN

INSERT @OrderStatus DEFAULT VALUES
SET @i = @i + 1;

END

SELECT * FROM @OrderStatus
```

Here's how to do it using a recursive CTE:

```
;with cteNums(n) AS
(
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n + 1
    FROM cteNums WHERE n < 100 -- how many times to iterate
)
INSERT @OrderStatus 
SELECT * FROM cteNums
```

Just note that for the CTE you'd have to specify `OPTION(MAXRECURSION ...)` if it's greater than 100.  Also note that even though you're selecting a list of numbers from the CTE, they don't actually get inserted into the table.

Answer (score 13):

An easier way is:

```
insert dbo.OrderStatus default values
go 500
```

this will insert 500 rows of default values.

Comment: I'm trying to make the inserts inside of a `BEGIN .. END` block. Is there a way to use your solution in that case or (should I / must I) stick with the while loop?

Comment: 'Go' is a SSMS command and not part of SQL or TSQL.This means that you cannot use it as part of a proc or script.

Comment: This is easy if you're just doing it in SSMS or SqlCmd.    You can't use it in a SP or function.

Comment: @benjaminmoskovits Could you specify it in your answer? It might be clearer for newcomers, since my question doesn't include the SSMS tag.

Comment: When you are working in SQL Server Management Studio in a query window you are in 'SSMS' mode and Go is available to you. It is interpeted by SSMS.  If you write a stored procedure it is often referred to as a 'proc' and when the SQL Server engine encounters GO it will probably throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

The Tally Table method can insert large sets of multiple rows, providing the tally table is big enough. This Tally table will handle up to 1000 entries.

```
WITH Tally (n) AS
(
    -- 1000 rows
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) a(n)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) b(n)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) c(n)
)
--SELECT * FROM Tally;

Create Table #temp (id int, d datetime, GUID uniqueidentifier, str1 nvarchar(1), number int)

insert into #temp
select n, getdate(), newid(), 'a', 101 from tally 
where N<=100 -- THIS IS WHERE YOU INDICATE HOW MANY ROWS

select * from #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do something similar...inserting ~24,000 records into our warehouse rack system. So..

If you have a table that already has the number of records you're inserting into the new table you can do something like this:

```
;with t as (
    select top 10000  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) n
    from products -- we really only need 60 but for the purpose of this example...
)
--insert into binlocs (warehouse, zone, row, rack, shelf, bin)
SELECT 101 warehouse, 20 zone, tRow.n row ,tRack.n rack, tShelf.n shelf, tBin.n bin
FROM t tRow
    join t tRack on tRack.n<=case -- how many racks per row
                                    when tRow.n=1 then 37 
                                    when tRow.n=2 then 38 
                                    when tRow.n=3 then 60
                                    when tRow.n=4 then 60 
                                    when tRow.n=5 then 60 
                                    when tRow.n=6 then 40 
                                    when tRow.n=7 then 40 
                                    when tRow.n=8 then 40 
                                    when tRow.n=9 then 38 
                                    when tRow.n=10 then 38 
                                end
    join t tShelf on tShelf.n<7 -- default to 6 shelves per rack
    Join t tBin on tBin.n<10 -- default to 9 bins per shelf
where tRow.n<=10 -- we need 10 rows
order by tRow.n,tRack.n,tShelf.n,tBin.n
```

Answer (score -2):

Set up a trigger when a new row is CREATEd:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx

Comment: This method is not efficient (recursion), and somewhat constrained to always adding the same number of rows, and would require a batch column key for termination of the trigger loop. However, +10 for creativity!