# increment empty SQL column from 1 to N (SQL server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have created a table called *table1* which has a column called *column1*.

How can I populate *column1* with (e.g.) 1000 rows in which each row has a unique number going from 1 to 1000? The first row has number 1, the second 2, the third has 3, etc.

Comment: What database do you use? Sql Server, Oracle, mySQL...

Comment: my apologies, I use SQL server. I forgot to precise it, I edit my post and added it to the title! :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30741629/how-to-insert-n-rows-of-default-values-into-a-table

Comment: pretty much all DBMS can do this. Exactly how depends on which youre using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
DECLARE @i INT = 1
WHILE @i <= 1000
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table1 (column1) VALUES (@i)
  SET @i = @i + 1
END
```

Comment: Thanks but, the code does not specify column1, Can you explain why there is do not need to specify that we want to increment column1?  What if I have multiple columns?

Comment: @dll I edited it to specify the column. Sorry I took your question literally as you had a table with a single column in it.

Comment: No problem, thanks it works !

Comment: Why use a loop for this?