# How to add 3000 rows to an existing table in SQL

Tags: sql

I need to add customers to an SQL table where the key is the customer `CardNo` which is a sequential range starting at `0040101006502` and ending at `0040101013349`.

In addition I need to put the same information into 9 fields in the table and leave the other fields `null`.

```
Cardno [from Range], Fname = "Welcome", Lname= "VIC", Address = "123 Any Rd", Address2 = "Dummy Town", Frequent Shopper = TRUE, Coupons = TRUE, CustomerType = 3, CustomerStatus = 4
```

This way the record is created in advance and when a new customer is to be added they just go into the record and change the name and address.
It's admittedly a bit goofy but they claim that it saves them a lot of time and errors doing it this way.

I have no idea how to do this.  The examples that I have seen have me typing in all of the data values manually line by line in the code to have it insert the data.  If I was going to do it that way I could just as easily gone into Management studio and done one row at a time as an insert and be done doing it manually in a year or so!

Comment: Please refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30741629/how-to-insert-n-rows-of-default-values-into-a-table).

Comment: 1) Make a spreadsheet of the data 2) Use excel CONCATENATE() function to make an INSERT statement for each row of data 3) Copy/Paste your insert statements into SSMS and execute

Comment: What type of SQL server is this on anyway? SQL Server? MySQL? Something else?

Comment: This may not be the best way to add customer default. You could use defaults in the SQL table definition. It might be better to do this in the business logic that creates the new customer.
I'd recommend against pre filling the database like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
Declare @i As BigInt = 0;
Declare @cardnostart As BigInt = 40101006502;

while (@i < 3000) Begin

    Insert Into customers 
    (
        CardNo,
        FName,
        LName,
        [Address],
        Address2,
        FrequentShopper,
        Cuopons,
        CustomerType,
        CustomerStatus

    ) Values (

        RIGHT ('0000000000000' + Cast(@cardnostart + @i As nvarchar(13)), 13),
        Null,
        Null,
        Null,
        Null,
        Null,
        Null,
        Null,
        Null

    );  

    Set @i = @i + 1;

End;
```

Comment: This looks exactly like what I want to do!  Thanks so much, I will give it a try.

Comment: I set it up and it worked PERFECTLY!!!   You have no idea of how much you helped me.   Thanks again!

Comment: So, set as 'Usefull' pls ;)

Comment: How do I  do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO dbo.OrderStatus(Fname, Lname, Address, Address2, [Frequent Shopper], Coupons, CustomerType, CustomerStatus) 
VALUES (Welcome,'VIC','123 Any Rd','Dummy Town', TRUE, TRUE,3, 4)

GO 3000
```

On SQL Server this will perform the task 3000 times. You can edit the INSERT statement to fit your needs, I brought it as close as I could using the provided information. the GO statement will execute whatever is above it X amount of times.